# Как добавлять вкладки в TabHost из Java-кода?

Tags: android, java

Видел много примеров с xml-разметкой. А как их добавлять из кода?

Я хочу просто создавать `View` и устанавливать её как контент. А на вкладке был текст `text`.

И что означает `tag` для `TabSpec`. Я написал такой код, но падает исключение:

```
TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = myTabHost.newTabSpec(text); 
tabSpec.setIndicator(text); 
tabSpec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() { 
  public View createTabContent(String text) { 
    (View) view; 
  } 
}); 
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гугл рулит http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1132

Comment: Я воспользовался этим примером и вкладки появились. Но мне нужно, чтобы на заголовке вкладки был не просто текст или изображение с текстом, а мой `View`. Там задается просто 

    ts1.setIndicator("TAB-1");

Еще есть 2 варианта этого метода: передать текст и картинку, и передать полностью свою вьюшку. Я передаю свою вьюшку и у меня табики не выглядят как табики. То есть получается, что этого просто прямоугольная панель без всякиx закруглений! Как исправить???

Comment: закругления - это 9-patch-бекграунды! сделайте их правильно и будут вам закругления, http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/113623/#comment_3655141

Comment: @orangeudav, спасибо. Надеюсь, поможет!
У меня нет поля `R.drawable.bg`. Я думал, что это что-то из библиотеки.

>Да, только что попробовал. Можно для каждой вкладки
>`mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg));`

Comment: Всё. Разобрался.