# Полоса внизу компонента TabWidget

Tags: android, java

Я воспользовался компонентом `TabHost` (и `TabWidget`) так, как мне подсказали в этой теме: [Как добавлять вкладки в TabHost из Java-кода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/49017/)

Но появилась другая проблема. Как мне добиться правильного отображения полосы внизу компонента `TabWidget`? Сейчас у меня там вообще никакой полосы нет. Хотя я написал такой код:

```
tabWidget.setStripEnabled(true);
tabWidget.setRightStripDrawable(right_id);
tabWidget.setLeftStripDrawable(left_id);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти табы полностью кастомизируемы. Например можно сделать как в айфоне:

[Iphone-Tab-in-Android](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android)

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что наверняка топикстартеру уже не нужно, но тк. я натолкнулся на аналогичную проблему - напишу ответ.

> Как мне добиться правильного
> отображения полосы внизу компонента
> TabWidget?

Где-то в коде есть примерно такой кусок кода или аналогичный:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec( ... );
spec.setContent( ... );
spec.setIndicator( ... );
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

так вот: установка всего, что связано с вашими "Strip" - а именно

```
tabWidget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
tabWidget.setStripEnabled(true);
tabWidget.setRightStripDrawable(right_id);
tabWidget.setLeftStripDrawable(left_id);
```

должна идти **после** того, как вы устанавливаете вью для закладок.

Все потому, что когда вы назначаете "кастомный вью", фреймворк вызывает tabWidget.setStripEnabled(false)